# Using haystack with Whoosh

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, whoosh

Requires setting HAYSTACK_WHOOSH_PATH to the place on your filesystem where the Whoosh index should be located.
Can anyone explain where exactly this path is pointing? I mean what should i give in this path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any directory where you have write access will do, as long as its filesystem has enough space to store the Whoosh index, like `/home/mysite/whoosh_index` (straight from the [docs](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/settings.html)). Just make sure the contents aren't made public by the webserver.

Answer (score 3):

Any directory you wish. You can use this configuration:

```
import os, sys
PROJECT_ROOT      = os.path.dirname(__file__)
HAYSTACK_WHOOSH_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'search_index')
```